# localforage and axios-extensions: Wrapping the get method to return undefined outside of a promise?

Tags: typescript, axios, localforage

I'm trying to use `axios-extensions` and `localforage` to create an axios cache adapter that uses the `localforage` library for its storage (our codebase is dated and I'm looking to replace the old `axios-cache-adapter`, which is not updated for the newest axios version). I'll abstract away some of the details here to make the situation simpler:

`localforage` has a get method with a signature like this:

`get(key: string): Promise<string | undefined>`

However, the `axios-extensions` cache adapter function expects a method with a signature like this:

`get(key: string): Promise<string> | undefined`

It feels like it should be simple to write a wrapper for `localforage`'s `get`, but I haven't found a way to do it yet without something ridiculous like busy-waiting. Is there any way to wrap the `localforage` `get` function in order to synchronously return undefined, even though I can't know if a field exists until the promise resolves? Do I really need to use a different library/create a patch for this one in order to do this?